# How to remove the blue background when clicking on an object multiple times?

Tags: css

I am finishing a merry-go-round and the button to move the images back and forth is an icon. The problem here is that when I click several times a blue background appears, the same thing when you double-click on a text to select. Is it possible to remove this in css?

An image as an example

[image]